# plymouthd runs at 5% all the time

Tags: 16.04, plymouth

plymouthd seems to be continuously running at around 5% of cpu. This is something new; it didn't used to do that.

Is this normal? If not, what should I do?

Comment: I had the same or a similar issue in 16.04 LTS, that disappeared after an update & upgrade yesterday. For me the plymouth '5 dots' was running where the first text screen should be (via `ctrl + alt + F1` and the other text screeens were dead). Now it works like it should again.

Comment: See the same thing as comment above, but I am updated as of today. 'plymouth --quit' kills the daemon, and ctrl+alt+F? work as usual. Not sure if there are consequences of a killed plymouthd...

Comment: @MikeHanafey, 'plymouth --quit' doesn't kill it for me (or if it does, it restarts immediately). I don't know what ctrl-alt-F is. I killed the daemon with the kill command. The only consequences I noticed is that it seemed to take longer to shutdown.

Comment: My F? is just a wildcard notation for F1, F2,... Killing plymouthd is okay until you go to a console login, and return to GUI -- all input is lost (i.e. keyboard, mouse don't work)

Comment: To kill you need to 'sudo plymouth --quit'

Comment: @MikeHanafey, Oh, of course. I forgot the sudo. Thanks again, Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug opened at [bugs.launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/1766095)

Supporting information may help to get it addressed!

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'll try to add that supporting info. I wonder how much electricity this bug is wasting overall?

Comment: Thanks to you the report is now confirmed -- hopefully fixed soon...

Comment: just got a plymouth update today that I think has solved the problem.

Comment: I also thought the problem was fixed but on a subsequent reboot plymouthd was chewing up 5%! I have not bothered to reboot again to see if the problem is consistent...

Comment: You're right. False alarm! It's still running for me too.